Why are comments getting removed? Interacting with bot comments about posts being unclear
I noticed a bot make the following comment to the question On a ground rule double on a walk off play is there anyway that the hitter only gets one base.?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to
highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard
to tell exactly what you're asking.

I defended this claim by stating that the question was clear enough (posting my comment for the record):

I think the question is clear. Can it be more concise or better
formatted? Sure. But it's clear what's being asked is why one ground
rule walk-off scenario was awarded a single while another was awarded
a double

Another bot made a similar comment to this answer: Are Interceptions in football hard to defend since offense now plays defense?. The OP asked what was unclear about the answer. I agreed with OP's comment and posted the following comment of my own (which is no longer visible, so I'm going off memory):

Unclear apparently means verbose. The main points (lack of training,
out of position, injury avoidance) are covered with supporting detail
while answering the question posed in the title with the first sentence.

Why are bots making comments if they're going to be removed when interacted with? Unclear is tenuous in these cases (the argument can be made about the posts being verbose but verbose is not unclear) but calling that out with an explanation gets that set of comments deleted? What's the precedent for doing that?

I wasn't the mod that removed them, but I can give you the more general answer.
Comments are intended to be ephemeral; in particular, once they have served their purpose of clarifying a question or an answer, they should be removed.
In the case of the example you posted, the bot's comment was presumably found to be incorrect (as you and the OP noted), and so the comment was removed - along with the other comments, which now served no purpose.

Why do bots comment in these situations?

Bots post those comments based on the responses from users in review queues, to avoid them being harassed or attacked for providing their time and effort to perform the reviews in the first place.
